# php composer - my package with namespace and class

Tags: php, class, namespaces, composer-php

i have maybe primitive problem. I created my first package in composer. It is just one class in one namespace.

**composer.json**:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "UrlParser\\": "src/"
    }
},
...
```

**and i have this in: src/UrlParser/url.php**

```
<?php
namespace UrlParser;
class Url{
...
```

everything is OK, i uploaded my package into composer. I install it into my project, but when i call this:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$a = new UrlParser\Url("http://localhost/aaa.html");
```

i get this: Fatal error: Class 'UrlParser\Url' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ccc\01\index.php on line 3

I am new in composer and i try to google my problem, but i am lost :)
Thanks

Comment: I think you forgot run the command `composer dump-autoload -o`

Comment: thanks a lot. It is working

Comment: As a hint: you should not name your file `url.php` (with a lower-cased u) when your class is called `Url` (with an upper-cased u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was, that i didn´t do this:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
namespace UrlParser;
$a = new Url("http://localhost/aaa.html");
```

If it doesn't work, there's probably a problem with autoload that you didn't get the right way